Curve fitting a resonance Inductance graph
I need to do a curve fit for the graph below to be able to extrapolate the values in this formula: $$Z = \frac{R_s + j\omega L}{1 - \omega ^2 L C_p + j\omega R_s C_p}$$ Which is to say finding R_s and C_p, because L is known. All the methods of curve fitting I can find include an initial guess when using a very specific formula, which I am, but is there a way I can curve fit without an initial guesses?
Edit: this is the link to the data, I didn't know how to upload them in the original excel file.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qGYoinGCM93refn1a4q2y--FHOyI4vNTqiZ1pNHbTHA/edit?usp=sharing

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
import os
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Constants
L_n = 300 * (10**-6)  # Inductance in Henry

def process_csv(file_name):

    x = []
    y = []

    # Read data from the CSV file
    with open(file_name, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(reader)  # Skip header if there's one
        for row in reader:
            try:
                x.append(float(row[0]))  # 1st column (index 0) - X-axis
                y.append(float(row[1]))  # 3rd column (index 2) - Y-axis
            except ValueError:
                continue  # Skip rows with invalid data

    # Convert the lists to numpy arrays
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)

    # Remove duplicates by averaging y values for duplicate x values
    unique_x, indices = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
    average_y = np.array([y[indices == i].mean() for i in range(len(unique_x))])

    return unique_x, average_y

# Process the CSV file and get x, y data
x_data, y_data = process_csv('file_path.csv')

# Define the model function for the magnitude of impedance
def impedance_model(f, R_s, C_p):
    omega = 2 * np.pi * f  # Angular frequency
    Z_eq = (R_s + 1j * omega * L_n) / ((1 - omega**2 * L_n * C_p) + 1j * omega * R_s * C_p)
    return np.abs(Z_eq)  # Return the magnitude for curve fitting

# Initial guesses for R_s and C_p with bounds
initial_guesses = [1, 1e-7]  # Initial guesses
bounds = (0, [10, 1e-5])  # Bounds for R_s and C_p

# Perform curve fitting
popt, pcov = curve_fit(impedance_model, x_data, y_data, p0=initial_guesses, bounds=bounds)

# Extract fitted parameters
R_s_fit, C_p_fit = popt
print(f'Fitted R_s: {R_s_fit:.4f} Ohms')
print(f'Fitted C_p: {C_p_fit:.4e} Farads')

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, label='Data')  # Original data
plt.plot(x_data, impedance_model(x_data, *popt), label='Fitted Model', linestyle='--')  # Fitted curve
plt.xscale('log')  # Set x-axis to logarithmic scale
plt.xticks([10**i for i in range(5, 8)], [f'$10^{i}$' for i in range(5, 8)])  # Set specific ticks as powers of 10
plt.xlim(10**5, 10**7)
plt.ylabel("Impédance équivalente (\u03A9)")  # Unicode for ohm symbol
plt.xlabel(r'Fréquence (Hz)')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()



Can you show us your data? Because what data do you have?

I don't know if you can correlate any data with your frequency response because you have two unknowns that could produce an infinite amount of solutions. For instance if C is very tiny and R is very large, you could have the same frequency response if the opposite was true where C is very large and R is very tiny.

can you share the csv-file?

The impendace of your circuit is given by:
$$\vec{\text{Z}}_\text{i}=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}_\text{p}}\space\text{||}\space\left(\text{R}_\text{s}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_1\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}_\text{p}}\cdot\left(\text{R}_\text{s}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_1\right)}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}_\text{p}}+\text{R}_\text{s}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}_1}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{s}+\text{L}_1\omega\text{j}}{\displaystyle1-\text{C}_\text{p}\text{L}_1\omega^2+\text{C}_\text{p}\text{R}_\text{s}\omega\text{j}}\tag1$$
Where \$\displaystyle\alpha\vert\vert\beta:=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha\beta}{\displaystyle\alpha+\beta}\$.
So, when you've data on \$\displaystyle\left|\vec{\text{Z}}_\text{i}\right|\$ we can write:
$$\left|\vec{\text{Z}}_\text{i}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{s}^2+\left(\text{L}_1\omega\right)^2}{\displaystyle\left(1-\text{C}_\text{p}\text{L}_1\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\text{C}_\text{p}\text{R}_\text{s}\omega\right)^2}}\tag2$$
Notice that when \$\displaystyle\omega\to0\$, we get:
$$\lim_{\omega\space\to\space0}\left|\vec{\text{Z}}_\text{i}\right|=\text{R}_\text{s}\tag3$$
And notice that when \$\displaystyle\text{C}_\text{p}\text{R}_\text{s}<\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\text{L}_1\$:
$$\frac{\displaystyle\partial\left|\vec{\text{Z}}_\text{i}\right|}{\displaystyle\partial\omega}=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega:=\hat{\omega}=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{L}_1}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\displaystyle\sqrt{\text{L}_1\left(\text{L}_1+2\text{C}_\text{p}\text{R}_\text{s}^2\right)}-\text{C}_\text{p}\text{R}_\text{s}^2}{\displaystyle\text{C}_\text{p}}}\tag4$$
So, we can find the maximum with your value of \$\displaystyle\text{L}_1\$:
$$\hat{\left|\vec{\text{Z}}_\text{i}\right|}=\lim_{\omega\space\to\space\hat{\omega}}\left|\vec{\text{Z}}_\text{i}\right|=\frac{3\sqrt[4]{3}}{100\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\text{C}_\text{p}\left(3\sqrt{20000\text{C}_\text{p}\text{R}_\text{s}^2+3}-5000 \sqrt{3}\text{C}_\text{p}\text{R}_\text{s}^2-3\sqrt{3}\right)}}\tag5$$

Edit, let's say that the maximum occurs when \$\displaystyle\text{f}=10^7\space\text{Hz}\$ and \$\displaystyle\hat{\left|\vec{\text{Z}}_\text{i}\right|}=130\space\text{k}\Omega\$, we have the following solutions:
$$\text{C}_\text{p}\approx41.4601\space\text{fF}\space\text{and}\space\text{R}_\text{s}\approx129843\space\Omega\tag6$$
$$\text{C}_\text{p}\approx844.152\space\text{fF}\space\text{and}\space\text{R}_\text{s}\approx2762.95\space\Omega\tag7$$
Where \$\displaystyle\text{fF}\$ is femto Farad.

First off, there aren't enough data points around the resonant frequency. Whoever took the data needs an old fashioned scolding! The resonant frequency in the spreadsheet may not be the actual resonant frequency due to lack of data around resonance.
If you want to be pedantic about the situation, \$R\$ is frequency dependent due to eddy current and core losses. However, we can get by with a fixed value for \$R\$ for this exercise.
The capacitor value can be found from the LC resonant equation.
$$ C = {1 \over {L \; (2 \pi f_o)^2}} $$
For your case, \$f_o\$ = 2290867.653 Hz, \$L\$ = 300 uH
Thus, \$ \; C\$ = 16.089 pF
You can rearrange the impedance equation to solve for R since you know L, C, and |Z| at resonance. A closed form solution exists, i.e., you don't need to do an iterative solution. I'll let you do the algebra.
Or, you can use a SPICE simulator and adjust R for the correct impedance at resonance as shown below. I get somewhere around 139.1 ohms.

LTspice simulation of the data from the spreadsheet and a LCR circuit. X1 is a subcircuit with admittance data from your spreadsheet data (mag-phase data was converted in to complex admittance data). You can clearly see that there needs to be more data points around the resonant frequency.
X1 Subcircuit format:
*Subckt simulates admittance
*Data format: Freq(Hz)  G(mhos)  B(mhos)
.SUBCKT XDCRZ 1 2
G1 2 1 FREQ {V(2,1)}= R_I (
+ 10.00000         1.68508122E+00  -2.28600313E-04
+ 10.96478         1.70060173E+00  -5.17808553E-04
+ 12.02264         1.65296597E+00  -3.72100072E-04
+ 13.18257         1.64959690E+00  -4.45048636E-04
+ 14.45440         1.59970056E+00  -3.82678773E-04
                    ...
+ 6918309.70900    3.86734841E-04  4.21773832E-04
+ 7585775.75000    4.60415541E-04  4.33708455E-04
+ 8317637.71100    5.47842805E-04  4.30970409E-04
+ 9120108.39400    6.53712628E-04  3.97798542E-04
+ 10000000.0000    7.54730051E-04  2.73199587E-04
+ )
.ENDS XDCRZ

Another technique:
If you had more data points around the resonant frequency, you could use this technique to calculate the inductor's series resistance:
$$ R = 2 \; \pi \; L \; BW_{-6dB} $$
Where \$ BW_{-6dB} \$ = bandwidth at the half \$\Re(Z_{at\_ resonance})\$ points.
The simulated LCR circuit has a -6 dB bandwidth of 73757.5 Hz.Thus, R = 139.03 ohms. Fairly close to the actual value of 139.1 ohms used in the simulation.
